# Variable name empty when using "for f in directory" despite non-empty directory

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm connected to a remote machine via SSH as part of a bash script. After navigating to the directory, I run `ls` which confirms matching files are found. However, I then try to loop through the files and run other commands on them, and the variable is now empty.

Code:

```
    echo "DOING STUFF!"
    cd /mnt/slowdata/ls8_processing
    ls
    for f in *.tar.gz
    do
        echo $f
    done
```

Output:

```
DOING STUFF!
LC080330242019031901T1-SC20190606111327.tar.gz
LC080330242019042001T1-SC20190606111203.tar.gz
LC080330242019052201T1-SC20190606111130.tar.gz
LC080330252019030301T2-SC20190606111021.tar.gz
LC080330252019031901T1-SC20190606120750.tar.gz
LC080340232019031001T1-SC20190606111056.tar.gz
LC080340232019041101T1-SC20190606111215.tar.gz
LC080340242019031001T1-SC20190606111201.tar.gz
LC080340242019041101T1-SC20190606111250.tar.gz
LC080340242019052901T1-SC20190606111331.tar.gz
```

As can be seen via the output, the $f is picking something up, as there are the correct number of blank lines. However I wish to untar each file which I cannot do.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove special meaning of $ to pass it to the remote host as '$' else the variable will be expanded before you send the command to the remote host.

Keep in mind the for cycle will run regardless of whether the cd was successful.

```
ssh server1 << EOF
    cd /mnt/slowdata/ls8_processing
    ls
    for f in *.tar.gz
    do
        echo \$f
    done
EOF
```

---

My example show the difference:

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

f=123

ssh -i .ssh/keyauth.pem root@server1 << EOF
for f in ./*.log 
do 
        echo "\$f"
        echo "$f" 
done 
EOF
```

Output

```
[edvin@server2 ~]$ ./script.sh
./sepap-install.log
123
./sepfl-upgrade.log
123
./sep-install.log
123
./sepjlu-install.log
123
./sepui-install.log
123
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you. I then had issues with other ones before just giving up and putting the script on the remote host and running it there. Saved a lot of headache.